# How to change color of prompt from last exit code in ZSH?

Tags: shell, zsh, prompt

I have this piece of code in my .zshrc:

```sh
autoload -U colors && colors

function change_color() {
    if [[ "$?" = 0 ]]; then
    return "green"
  else
    return "red"
  fi
}

PS1="%B%{$fg[red]%}[%{$fg[yellow]%}%n%{$fg[green]%}@%{$fg[blue]%}%M %{$fg[magenta]%}%~%{$fg[red]%}]% %{$fg[$changecolor]%}➜%b "
```

However, the `➜` character stays white, no matter what I do.

Comment: You are using a variable `$changecolor`, which never gets assigned. But even if you would it assign to some value, `PS1` would get this value at the time the PS1 variable is defined, and would never change afterwards.

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel, you could for instance install [spaceship](https://spaceship-prompt.sh/) or at least look at its source code to learn how the Prompt change based on the status is implemented there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a function, you need to *call* it, not expand it as a variable. Do that with a command substitution:

```
PS1="...%{$fg[\$(changecolor)]%}➜%b "
```

However, there's a lot of `bash`-like stuff in this prompt that you can replace with simpler, more robust `zsh` features. First, `%F` can be used to change the color directly, without using escape codes stored in an array. (Unlike raw escape codes, and like other `zsh`-defined escape sequences, `%F{...}` doesn't need to be wrapped in `%{...%}`.) Second, there is prompt escape specifically for producing one value or another depending on whether the last exit status was 0 or not.

```
PS1='%B%F{red}[%F{yellow}%n%F{green}@%F{blue}%M '
PS1+='%F{magenta}%~%F{red}] %(?.%F{green}.%F{red})➜%b%f '
```

`%(?.FOO.BAR)` expands to `FOO` if the last command succeeded, `BAR` otherwise. `%f` restores the color to the default, regardless of any preceding `%F` codes.

---

`%(...)` is, in fact, more general than just testing the exit code. `?` is just one of 20 or so testable conditions. As a silly example, suppose your birthday is coming up on January 18. Here's an escape to put a cake in your prompt on your birthday.

```
%(0D.%(18d..).)
```

More information on prompt escape codes can be found in `man zshmisc`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helped me and solves many hours or torment over this :). My prompt is perfect now, thank you so much